# How do I keep my app windows (2 instances of same app) from combining?

Tags: taskbar

How do I keep my app windows (2 instances of same app) from combining? I'm having a hard time switching between apps because I use one of my applications to open two windows and their icons are the same in the taskbar. I recently switched from Windows OS.

Comment: It's pretty standard to switch between apps with `Alt + Tab` and between multiple windows of the app using `Alt + (backtick)`

Comment: Alt + (backtick) did the trick. Thank you so much!

Comment: `Alt + <- ` !!!

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a single icon for a single application, even if that has multiple windows. It is not possible to reconfigure the dock to show an icon for each window.

- By default, you can switch between windows of that application by clicking on the icon. Miniatures of the open window are displayed, and you can select the window you want:

  [image]
- Alternatively, you can make it so that each click on the application icon brings a different window in focus. To achieve that, change a setting with the following command in a terminal:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'cycle-windows'
  ```

  To undo, remove the part `'cycle-windows'`, and change `set` to `reset`.
- With the keyboard, you can switch windows of the same application only with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`(kay above tab)</kbd>. In Ubuntu, with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> you switch between all open windows, with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you switch between applications.
- If you would prefer to have separate icons for separate windows, you could consider using the "[Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/)" extension. That extension moves the top panel to the bottom, and places the launcher icons on it, giving the desktop an MS Windows like layout. That extension can be configured to show separate icons for separate windows, and even to also show labels, giving the look and feel of a traditional taskbar.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailed answer! I will try to use those also.